# Java gif splashscreen strange bug

Tags: java, swing, splash-screen

Today, i have tested to show a gif with the java splashscreen option.
It's working, but... At the repeat of the splashscreen, my gif show a strange graphical bug...

[image]

This bug appear only in the java application.

This is the original gif :

[image]

The code

```
public class Bootstrap {
private SplashScreen splash;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
    bootstrap.start();
}

public void start() {

    // Here i load the splash
    splash = new SplashScreen("UC", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("splash3.gif")).getImage());
    AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(splash, false);
    splash.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

SplashScreen.java

```
public class SplashScreen extends JFrame {
public SplashScreen(String title, Image image) {
    this.setTitle(title);
    this.setUndecorated(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    this.setSize(image.getWidth(this), image.getHeight(this));
    this.setLocationRelativeTo((Component)null);
    this.setContentPane(new SplashPanel(image));
}
}
```

Splashpanel.java

```
class SplashPanel extends JPanel {
private Image image;

public SplashPanel(Image image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this);
}
}
```

**Apparently this is simply because gif is interlaced. :) Just uncheck this when you export your gif from photoshop... :)**

Comment: Please consider posting the code you use to display the graphic. Does the graphical abnormality fix itself over time?

Comment: @AndrewFan added ! And nope, the problem not fixing itself over time

Comment: Anyone for help me ? :)

Comment: Problem found, just unchecked the case "Entrelaced mode" in photoshop and it solved my problem.

Comment: @Halvra add your own answer and accept it. might help people in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Apparently this is simply because gif is interlaced. Just uncheck this when you export your gif from photoshop... :)**